# Question regarding outer and inner measures defined on an Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)$
  be an Algebra and $\mu$
  be a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$
  ($\sigma-$
 addivity only applies to collections of disjoint sets for which the union belongs to $\mathcal{A}$
 ). We define the following outer measure on $\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)$
 : $$\mu_{e}\left(B\right)=\inf\left\{ {\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{j}\right)\;|\; A_{1},A_{2},...\in\mathcal{A}}\;,\; B\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j}\right\} $$
 We also define the inner measure of $B\in\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)$
 to be: $$\mu_{i}\left(B\right)=1-\mu_{e}\left(\Omega\backslash B\right)$$

Prove that for all $B\in\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)$
  there exist $E,F\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\right)$
  (the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$)
  such that $\mu_{e}\left(B\right)=\mu_{e}\left(E\right)$
  and $\mu_{i}\left(B\right)=\mu_{i}\left(F\right)$.
  I've been working on finding a suitable $E$
  for starters, so far I've managed to show that for all $\varepsilon>0$
  I can find a set $A_{\varepsilon}\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\right)$
  such that: $$\mu_{e}\left(A_{\varepsilon}\right)\leq\mu_{e}\left(B\right)+\varepsilon$$
 But I haven't managed to get any further and I'm not sure if this is even useful.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Consider the sequence $\varepsilon_n = \frac1n$ for example, and $\bigcap A_{\varepsilon_n}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the reply! The result of taking that intersection is very similar to the definition of liminf of a sequence of sets as each Aε I defined is an infinite unions of sets (but different sets for each $\varepsilon$), is that a coincidence or is there some actual relation?
Also Would the same construction for the complement result in a suitable $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I'm not sure if this is even useful.

It is very useful. In fact you're almost there (I'm supposing, although it is not explicitly stated, that you have $B \subset A_\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$). What remains is to construct from the $A_\varepsilon$ an $E\in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$ with $\mu_e(E) = \mu_e(B)$. Since we can only do countably many set operations without possibly leaving $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, we must choose a sequence $\varepsilon_n \to 0$ to obtain

$$E = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_{\varepsilon_n} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}).$$

Since $B \subset A_{\varepsilon_n}$ for all $n$, we have $B\subseteq E$, and by the monotonicity of the outer measure $\mu_e$, we have $\mu_e(B) \leqslant \mu_e(E)$, and for every $n$ we have $E\subset A_{\varepsilon_n}$, whence $\mu_e(E) \leqslant \mu_e(A_{\varepsilon_n}) \leqslant \mu_e(B) + \varepsilon_n$. Since $\varepsilon_n \to 0$, that implies $\mu_e(E) \leqslant \mu_e(B)$, together $\mu_e(E) = \mu_e(B)$.

> Also Would the same construction for the complement result in a suitable $F$?

It would indeed, since $\mu_i(M) = 1 - \mu_e(\Omega\setminus M)$ for all $M \subset \Omega$ gives us $$\mu_i(F) = \mu_i(B) \iff \mu_e(\Omega\setminus F) = \mu_e(\Omega\setminus B).$$

> The result of taking that intersection is very similar to the definition of $\liminf$ of a sequence of sets as each $A_\varepsilon$ I defined is an infinite unions of sets (but different sets for each $\varepsilon$), is that a coincidence or is there some actual relation?

It's different, but of course there is some similarity. What we do here is to approximate $B$ by a sequence of sets all containing $B$, and we take the $\inf$ of that sequence, which is the first step of getting the $\liminf$.